# How can I stream rtsp (live video) in django app?

Tags: django, opencv, streaming, rtsp

I tried to use StreamingHttpResponse in Django app for live rtsp streaming [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects].
But du to documentation it's not correct.
Does anyone have other solutions for this task?

````
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")```

A new way to solve this problem?
````